# jQuery set att value as integer

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to set jQuery custom attribute value as Integer instead of String. 
I would like to set the tabindex value dynamically using jQuery.

```
<input tabindex=1 /> 
var allInputs = new Array();
                        $(':input').each(
                                function() {
                                    allInputs.push($(this));
                                }
                            );

                        $.each(allInputs, function (i) {
                            var indexNumber = i + 1;
                            $(this).attr('tabindex', indexNumber );
                        });
```

This code sets an value as a String within "".

```
 e.g <input tabindex="1" />
```

Is there any other ways to set the value as an Integer so It will be

```
<input tabindex=1 />
```

/Jivan

Comment: you want to set tabindex value as string To int?

Comment: Elements' attributes are always string. You can't set them as numbers. You can use them as numbers in your script or whereever you like by type casting them, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In HTML, [attribute value is **always** a string](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attributes).

Even if you omit quotes, it will be assumed that they are there.

```
<input tabindex=1 />
```

is **strictly exact** the same thing that

```
<input tabindex="1" />
```

On rendering, the browser knows that tabindex string value is a number and do the parse internally. If it's not a number, browser will ignore it.

In fact, it's recommended using always quotes. That's the why when even set attribute value with integer (paseInt or not), the browser will wrap it into the quotes.. (or even jQuery wrapping explicitly into quotes)

Don't worry about the quotes, keep coding and be happy :)

Comment: it's more logical then to parse it as a number when using it.

Comment: @PratikJoshi, desperation doesn't change the DOM elements' behaviour :)